# What would be best practice of client comunication in a multiplayer game

Tags: multiplayer, client-server, websocket

Assume that we have a multiplayer game and the users are moving their characters (might be a circle) on the game area. At every game loop some changes can be happened. Should clients send their changes at every game loop to the server ? What would be best practice to comunicate clients each others by avoding overloading server?

Note: I'm asking this question for mostly HTML5 multiplayer games and will be using Box2D.

Answer (score 3):

I'm far from an expert but I've been working on an HTML5 version of Pong that uses Websockets for multiplayer so I can share what's been working for me. The general maxim I've been living by is:

```
"Send the minimal amount of information necessary as infrequently as possible."
```

In my case I maintain the state of the keyboard by listening for the `keyup` and `keydown` events in the client. When one of these events is fired the client sends a message to the server and then updates its own state. This allows the client to employ client-side prediction (see [this article](http://gafferongames.com/networking-for-game-programmers/what-every-programmer-needs-to-know-about-game-networking/) for more details) and gives the server the minimal amount of information it needs to execute the move.

When the server receives one of these events it updates its own internal state and then rebroadcasts the event to all other clients so they can handle it as well.

To keep everything in sync the server will periodically (every 10 ticks of the engine in my case) send a "sync state" message to all of the clients giving them the exact positions of all players. You never want to sync the state of a client to the server as that opens up all sorts of cheating opportunities.

**EDIT**

To be clear, state syncing should only ever go *from* the server *to* the client, never the other way around.

**END EDIT**

I found [Maple.js](https://github.com/BonsaiDen/Maple.js) to be quite useful as a reference for a concrete implementation in Javascript.

Comment: I believe you meant "never sync the server to the client", although I don't want to just make that edit in case I misunderstood you.

Comment: @jhocking I think you misunderstood him. He says "the server will .... send a "sync state" message to all of the clients", and that is correct. You only want to send movement events to the server, not the player position, because the server will then run the same logic for everyone, so it will effectively limit the type of client side cheating. When the server syncs to the client, it sends the correct positions, not the possibly cheated ones.

Comment: hm perhaps what I'm misunderstanding here is the directionality of the expression "sync A to B". To me, that would mean making the state of A match the state of B, whereas it sounds like you mean the other way around.

Comment: @jhocking Is this the sentence you are referring to: "You never want to sync the state of a client to the server as that opens up all sorts of cheating opportunities." Based on the comments I think we're all thinking the same things, but my original statement is not clearly worded. I've editing my answer to clarify this point.

Comment: looks good to me, at this point

Answer (score 1):

There is usually no good reason for the clients to send their positions at every game loop, because in most situations their positions will either not change at all or change in a very predictable way (because they are moving with a constant speed in a constant direction).

To avoid a storm of lots of redundant network packages, you should just report changes in movement.

Also keep in mind that all game mechanics should happen on the server. When a client says that it moves towards point x:y, the server should treat this as a request to do so, and only relay it to the other clients when its actually able to do it according to the game mechanics. When you don't do this, players will be easily able to cheat.

Answer (score 1):

What happens generally is that clients send their timestamped inputs to the server, then the server uses them to compute a new "world state", and sends it back to the clients.

That's it in a nutshell, but the devil is in the details. And there are tons of details :) I've written extensively about the topic, details and all, here: http://gabrielgambetta.com/fast_paced_multiplayer.html

Comment: And in case you're interested, I just added a **Sample Code and Live Demo** page to the articles: http://gabrielgambetta.com/fpm_live.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but i thought that the best practice is send the player input from the client side only when change (for example if the player is moving to left, not send infinite packages with 'left', only when starts or stop moving), and do all the game mechanics in the servers-side.